# Sort object by two entities one after the other

Tags: java

I have a class with the following variables (entities):

```
Identifier  
Entry_Number  
Rest_of_the_data
```

I'd like to sort the instances of this class as follows:
Sort the instances by the `Identifier` variable, then for instances with the same `Identifier` values, sort them by the `Entry_Number` variable.

I know I can implement Comparable with one of these entities as the key, but I don't know how to go about this to sort sequentially on two entities.
That is, after sorting by the `Identifier` when I sort by the `Entry_Number`, the initial sorting should not be disturbed - the second sorting should apply only to those instances with the same `Identifier` values.

So, in effect, I want to be able to pass as "second key" item to resolve ties.

Comment: You can do this with Comparable. If identifiers are equal then compare by entry_number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can compare by two fields almost as easily as you can by one. Create a [`Comparator<YourClass>` instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with the following `compare()` method:

```
public int compare(YourClass a, YourClass b) {
    int idDiff = a.getIdentifier().compareTo(b.getIdentifier());
    if (idDiff != 0) {
        return idDiff;
    }
    return a.getEntryNumber().compareTo(b.getEntryNumber());
}
```

If you have null values, or primitives, you will have to adjust.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of [Guava `ComparisonChain`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ComparisonChain.html):

```
public int compare(X a, X b) {
    return ComparisonChain.start()
     .compare(a.id, b.id)
     .compare(a.dateField, b.dateField)
     .result();
}
```

Note that this is *lazy* comparison, it means that comparisions are performed until first non-zero (meaning not-equal) result is found.